# How to set a rule option count in ANTLR

Tags: antlr

I need help setting the count for an option match in a rule.
This rule example will match (rule2) zero or more times.

```
rule1: 'text' ( '(' rule2 ')' )*
```

I know +,*,? for counts but what if I want the (rule2) to match 5 times?

Are +,*,? the only count modifier supported for grammar so I need to enforce count in the parser listener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what if I want the (rule2) to match 5 times?

Inside the grammar, there are 2 options:

## 1.

write it out 5 times:

```
rule1: 'text' '(' rule2 ')' '(' rule2 ')' '(' rule2 ')' '(' rule2 ')' '(' rule2 ')'
```

## 2.

or use a semantic predicate. See paragraph *Using Context-Dependent Predicates* from the [ANTLR4 wiki about predicate](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Semantic+Predicates)

> Are +,*,? the only count modifier supported for grammar

Yes, there is no `(...){5}` syntax to match exactly 5 times.

> so I need to enforce count in the parser listener?

That would be the (IMO) best option: in the parser, just match `( '(' rule2 ')' )+`, and in a listener/visitor validate after parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to specify `*` or `+` in the grammar, and then use a listener after the parse is complete to verify that it appeared exactly *n* times. The alternative is to expand the expression in the grammar, but this can have disastrous consequences on the ability of the grammar to cleanly recover from syntax errors.

```
// this is allowed, but not recommended as described in the text above
rule1
  : 'text'
    '(' rule2 ')'
    '(' rule2 ')'
    '(' rule2 ')'
    '(' rule2 ')'
    '(' rule2 ')'
  ;
```