# Parsing ASN1 with ANTLR

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr3, asn.1

I have an assignment for my formal languages course. The teacher asked us to develop a lexer for ASN1 DER encoded file using a lexer generator. I chose ANTLR 3.5.2 since the lexer is basically a pushdown automata, instead of a FSA. I know that ASN1 is context-sensitive because of the length field, hence our teacher gives an upper bound on the length of the parsable ASN1 files of 512 bytes. Even if the counting is finite, I'm still stuck on it, because the only way I know to count using a context-free grammar is using a grammar with n rules, if I have to count n bytes. Moreover, 512 bytes is just an upper bound, hence in a length field there can be every number between 1 and 512, meaning that I have to count every number in that range. Thus I would need 512^2 rules in the grammar, which seems way too big. Do you know a smarter way to perform this task?

Comment: The fact that you are concerned about length fields leads me to believe that your task is to analyze a BER-encoded input, rather than the textual ASN.1 syntax description. But you should edit your question to make this more clear.

Comment: Yeah, your guessing is right! I have just added this information, thank you to point it out :)

Comment: That's an interesting problem.  First, I assume he wants you to develop a parser, not merely a lexer.  As for the length issue, I would guess he expects you to use whatever workarounds exist for your chosen tool to deal with context-sensitivity.  This link might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25212324/how-to-set-a-rule-option-count-in-antlr